# Ubergallery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

tried to call the Ubergallery through an Ajax I had a lot of problems and I solve them with the following script. 
Now everything work as I want except one thing I have no navigation buttons. Can you help me solve this problem?

You can see the buttons on the page that I call with ajax http://iliaspapantoniou.com/2/gallery.php
but when you call it http://iliaspapantoniou.com/2/index.htm menu music the buttons are not there.

Thank you in advance

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click", "a[rel='colorbox']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    $.colorbox({href: url, maxWidth: "99%", maxHeight: "99%", opacity: ".5"});
    });
    });
```

I tried  to solve this problem an I realize that the
         e.preventDefault (); 
dose not allow all images in the gallery to be readed and the clicked image seems to be the only one in the gallery
I think that is the reason I have no navigation buttons.
Can someone help me with the code. If I write it without the 
        e.preventDefault (); 
dose not work normal.
Thank you.

On index.htm I use this ajax code to call gallery.php

```
<script>
function gallery(){
var xmlhttp;
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// code for IE6, IE5
else{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML =         xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gallery.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

the gallery.php create this  things with the folowing code

```
<html>
<head>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Gallery/resources/themes/uber-naked/images/favicon.png" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gallery/resources/themes/uber-naked/rebase-min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gallery/resources/UberGallery.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gallery/resources/colorbox/5/colorbox.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gallery/resources/themes/uber-naked/style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Gallery/resources/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
 });
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>


 <?php include_once('Gallery/resources/UberGallery.php'); $gallery = UberGallery::init()->createGallery('Gallery/gallery-images'); ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

When I open the gallery.php evrything is ok when i call it with ajax script I have no navigation buttons.
You need tou include the first script on index.htm to work the gallery
Can anyone tell me why this thing hapens

Comment: you need to add those anchors to index.html like you have it in gallery.php - check the source of that html, there you can see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly I found the solution I call the gallery.php with an iframe

```
<iframe id="iframeResult" frameborder="0" src="gallery.php" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

and i call the page with the iframe (music.html) with AJAX

```
<script>
function Music()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","files/Music.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The only problem is that the photos growth as big as the iframe

Answer (score 0):

In **index.html** there is no element `<a>` with `rel='colorbox'`.

Comment: OP comments: `I have no idea how to add this element without breaking this code` (note: this was extracted from edited content of the answer). If you think you can help him with this, then consider enhancing your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in edition history - didn't know that with that rep one can edit answers.